# Backwards logic: playing with fire : run .hta as front end gui, and java /sqlite as backend?

Tags: java, user-interface, frontend, hta

I have an insane idea: use .hta file as the gui front end of a java application.
(for those who do not know - .hta = .html file uses IE as a browser engine : a trusted version of the browser - with read / write files permissions)

Therefore when java application is loaded, get java application to write an .hta file and launch it.

Questions that need answering:
1) I need a way to communicate data between front end and back end and vice versa.
My thoughts: save the form to a xml file format - and get java to read that file, and vice versa.

2) I need a way to trigger the java program to know whether to upload / download data, and for the front end to know whether to update data.

My thoughts: have a local file as a boolean and simply listen to that file for changes.
Is this a good / bad idea?

3) Should I rewrite the .hta file each time the application is launched to prevent malicious injection, or am I playing with fire if I use .hta files.

I know. Everyone will snort with scorn. But a html / css / javascript front end is very quick to write compared to a swing interface. Add JQuery and you have animations ready to rock and roll. Do that in as short a time frame in pure java? I don't think so.

Comment: Actually this is not such a bad idea except that instead of using IE specific .hta files, try using [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/docs/JxBrowser-PGuide.html). Your application will run on all platforms just like your Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use htas for front ends for providing a gui for SAS macros all the time.  you can pass arguments to the hta file by putting them on the command line (c:\filename.hta param1|param2|param3 and retrieving them using .commandLine property.  i pass data to SAS as a text or xml file.